# Javascript syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a syntax error that I am missing ";" before statement var numDashes += '-';

I am just trying to pass a number to a dashes method and add the respective number of dashes using recursion. Sorry i'm a Java person. Please help.

```
function dashes(number) {
 for (var i=0; i<number; i++){
 var numDashes += '-';
 }
 return numDashes;  
 } 



console.log(dashes(3))
```

Comment: Use http://www.jslint.com/ to validate your JavaScripit.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `numDashes` first with an empty string.

```
function dashes(number) {
 var numDashes = '';
 for (var i=0; i<number; i++){
   numDashes += '-';
 }
 return numDashes;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dashes(number) {
var numDashes = "";
 for (var i=0; i<number; i++){
    numDashes += '-';
 }
 return numDashes;  
 } 

console.log(dashes(3))
```

This should work :) When creating a variable always initialized with something. Otherwise it will be as 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Above answer are correct. you can't apply any operation when you define variable. First need to be define variable after that you can implement any operation. So, define "numDashes" variable before loop and than apply "+=" operator in loop.

Correct Syntax:

```
function dashes(number) {
var numDashes = "";
 for (var i=0; i<number; i++){
    numDashes += '-';
 }
 return numDashes;  
} 

console.log(dashes(3))
```